# PayPal Secure way to process order

Tags: php, paypal

I'm currently developing a website that uses PayPal for order processing..
This is the html form I'm using so far for testing purpose

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">

<select name="amount">
<option value="3.99">6 Months ($3.99)</option>
<option value="5.99">12 Months ($5.99)</option>

</select>
<br>
<input name="currency_code" type="hidden" value="USD">
<input name="shipping" type="hidden" value="0.00">
<input name="tax" type="hidden" value="0.00">
<input name="return" type="hidden" value="urlOnValidPayment">
<input name="cancel_return" type="hidden" value="UrlOnCancelPayment">
<input name="notify_url" type="hidden" value="URLForValidationPayement">
<input name="cmd" type="hidden" value="_xclick">
<input name="business" type="hidden" value="your e-mail">
<input name="item_name" type="hidden" value="name of the object">
<input name="no_note" type="hidden" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
<input name="lc" type="hidden" value="EN">
<input name="bn" type="hidden" value="PP-BuyNowBF">
<input name="custom" type="hidden" value="custom data">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/CH/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/fr_FR/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

But, I've noticed that, this method is not secure for ordering purpose. it can be only used for donation purpose. Because, user may return to the url in "notify_url" field without paying. blah blah..
Am I right? Or is there any way to make it secure?

Comment: What is the issue with the user going to the URL? You can't assume they have paid just because they access that page. You need to confirm the payment goes through (ex. An IPN notification)

Comment: yuo IPN is the answer, make sure you reconcile the amount's as well

Comment: thank you.. need to read the IPN documentation :)

Comment: @Dagon [PDT](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/paymentdatatransfer/) may be a better choice here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reconcile the item amount within an IPN script, but this can be more trouble than its worth in my opinion.  Since you're already working with PHP I'd recommend using the [Express Checkout API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted/) instead of standard payment buttons.  This makes everything much more secure and allows you to fully integrate without any limitations.

You can take a look at my [PHP class library for PayPal](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library) if you want.  It'll make the API calls very simple for you. Specifically, you'd be looking at [SetExpressCheckout](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/), [GetExpressCheckoutDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetExpressCheckoutDetails_API_Operation_NVP/), and [DoExpressCheckoutPayment](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoExpressCheckoutPayment_API_Operation_NVP/).